# Kafka Connect + Camel + DynamoDB sink: int type overflow

Tags: apache-kafka, amazon-dynamodb, apache-camel, apache-kafka-connect

I use [Camel DynamoDB sink connector](https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/next/reference/connectors/camel-aws-ddb-sink-kafka-sink-connector.html) with the following configuration

```
{
"connector.class": "org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.awsddbsink.CamelAwsddbsinkSinkConnector",
"name": "dynamodb_sink_connector",
"camel.kamelet.aws-ddb-sink.operation": "PutItem",
"kafka.bootstrap.servers": "my-bootstrap-servers",
"topics": "my-topic",
"camel.kamelet.aws-ddb-sink.table": "my-dynamodb-table",
"camel.kamelet.aws-ddb-sink.writeCapacity": "1",
"camel.kamelet.aws-ddb-sink.useDefaultCredentialsProvider": "true",
"camel.kamelet.aws-ddb-sink.region": "eu-central-1"
}
```

and the target DynamodDB table has a sort key declared with `Number` type. When I send messages with integer values that fit the Java int type everything works fine, but if this value is bigger than `2147483647` the connector fails with this error

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DynamoDbException: 
One or more parameter values were invalid: Type mismatch for key mySortKey expected: N actual: S
```

It seems like the connector tries to convert the value to a string. Is there any way to make the connector use the `long` type instead of `int`?

Comment: Camel is an open source, you could try looking at where the intValue function is used on the Number type rather than longValue